# How to make Node.js to use virtual memory?

Tags: node.js, virtual-memory

I have an application that needs ton of memory and my own memory is not enough for that. I've about 30GB virtual memory  set on Windows.

I've tried forcing node to run under 30GB by using `--max-old-space-size=30000` but it crash.

Windows has `virtualalloc` API to allocate virtual memory. I suppose NodeJS isn't using it and relay on some automatic mechanism?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the memory allocation to 10GG? Also, check process.memoryUsage() in any file to see the process memory. No, It does take the memory allocation by this command, but try using lesser memory first. The crash might occurs may be due to some other reason too.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara It seems max-old-space-size doesn't use virtual memory. I think I have to re-write whole thing in C++

Comment: It seems like you can't add virtual memory, but does it take memory when we run in containers? I googled it, but unable to much literature related to virtual memory allocation.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06358.pdf